# How to play a sound for watch kit app

Tags: ios, watchkit

From what I understand it is currently not possible to play a sound from your watch kit app on the watch. If this is the case what is the best way to play a sound? Currently I am using `openParentApplication:reply:` to run code on the phone that plays the sound. Is this the best way?

*Update:* I also found that I can play audio directly from the watch extension using the same methods as in the parent app. No Idea if this will actually play when not on the simulator.

Comment: The WatchKit API is still in beta so people cannot really talk about it here.  You will need to use the forum on Apple Developer Site.

Comment: Considering the WatchKit documentation is publicly available, I don't see what's wrong with talking about it here.

Comment: Although in the past Apple has been extremely strict about developer NDA's for their Betas, this time around for both iOS8 and WatchKit, Apple has not bothered to restrict developers to a NDA. As a result, we can publicly discuss it with no issues.

Answer (score 4):

There currently isn't any way to play audio on the Watch. Your assumptions are 100% correct. Apple doesn't want to have to transfer the audio clips from the Watch Extension to the Watch at runtime. Currently, the only supported transfer caching system is for [images](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/Images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH20-SW1). For now, you will have to play the audio on the iOS device. You can use one of the following approaches to trigger playing the sound:

- `openParentApplication:reply:` - opens app in the background if not currently running
- Darwin notifications through something like [MMWormhole](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMWormhole)

Playing the sound from the Watch extension is certainly a gray area. My guess is that it will play on the iOS Device or not play at all when testing with devices. I would certainly advise against that approach though. Your Watch Extension will typically only be open for a VERY short period of time. It would be a much better idea to play the audio from the iOS app since that is guaranteed to continue running.

Comment: Hi @datinc, did this answer help you solve your issue? If yes, could you mark the answer as such? Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

As of watchOS 2, you can play audio files using `WKAudioFilePlayer` on the watch. It appears that mp3 files are not supported, but caf and wav are. Copy the sound file to the extension target.

Setup:

```
NSURL *assetURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"file" withExtension:@"wav"];
WKAudioFileAsset *asset = [WKAudioFileAsset assetWithURL:assetURL];
WKAudioFilePlayerItem *playerItem = [WKAudioFilePlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
WKAudioFilePlayer *audioFilePlayer = [WKAudioFilePlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
```

Play:

```
if (audioFilePlayer.status == WKAudioFilePlayerStatusReadyToPlay) {
        [self.audioFilePlayer play];
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the `WKInterfaceMovie` class:

```
[self presentMediaPlayerControllerWithURL:assetURL options:nil completion:nil];
```

Comment: Hey there, I have tried your solution but it pops up a message to pair bluetooth headset. You know anything about it?

Comment: Just to make things clear. A bug in the SDK, but you should be able to play a sound on simulator and even on real device **without a bluetooth headset** ?

Comment: The Apple Docs don't make any mention of requiring a bluetooth headset, so assume it is not required.

Comment: This appears to be either a design flaw or classic Apple "we will decide the use cases for you" mentality. As is, there's no way to play a brief sound on the watch without either popping up an intrusive media controller that the user must dismiss, or requiring use of a Bluetooth speaker. This is something Apple honestly needs to address, as custom alert sounds or short in-app sounds on the watch could be quite useful for many apps and situations.

Comment: It is required to bluetooth headset paired with apple watch in order play using  WKAudioFilePlayer

Comment: Is it possible the above code for playback of streaming radio? How to playback m3u files (streaming audio)??